# Use Select.Creatable with React Final Form

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-final-form, final-form

We are having a form which is React Final Form, and want a select and create able field in that form.

How can i use such component inside react final form.

Currently I tried using Select.Creatable of react-select inside the form, but as soon as i select something from dropdown and update the state, the form gets clear i.e back to its initial state.

Kindly help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All React Final Form does is manage the form values. To use any third party component, all you need is to accept the `value` that React Final Form gives you, and change it using the `onChange` callback that React Final Form gives you.

Look at the "adapter" components defined in the [Third Party Components](https://codesandbox.io/s/40mr0v2r87) example for guidance.